# \setstretch affect line out side of group

Tags: setspace

I have a error where the `\setstretch` command stretch the space between `line 1` and `line 2` as well as the space between two group:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} % provides "\rotatebox" and "\reflectbox" macros
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Something} line 1 \\
line 2 \\
\begingroup
\setstretch{10}
\-\hspace{24pt}f) group line 1.1\\
\-\hspace{24pt}g) group line 1.2\\
\endgroup $\phantom{}$ \\
\textbf{Theorem}\, line 3 \\
line 4\\
\begingroup
\setstretch{5}
\-\hspace{24pt}group line 2.1\\
\-\hspace{24pt}groupline 2.2\\
\-\hspace{24pt}group line 2.3\\
\par
\endgroup$\phantom{}$\\
line 5
\end{document}
```

if i remove the second group (remove everything after `line 4` except `\end{document}`), the spacing in the first group becomes normal spacing no matter what value i set to it, can someone tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: First of all, don't end lines with ``\\``.

Comment: what should i change it to ?

Comment: My impression is that you're asking an XY-question. What's your real aim?

Comment: i'm trying to limit the line spacing to only the lines in the group command but not the lines above and below it.